# htaccess : web and alias.web

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a small problem with two *.htaccess files*.

The first allows me to manage my first website (*website.com*) and the second allows me to manage my second website (*dev.website.com*).

The second site is located in a **"dev"** folder at the **same level as my first website**.

What I want to do:

If the user writes **website.com/dev**, I would like it to be redirected to *website.com* **and not to my second site**.

By cons, if he writes **dev.website.com**, I would like it to be redirected to my *second website*.

Here is my first .htaccess (website.com) :

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error404.html

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Stuff to let through (ignore)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/folder1/" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/folder2/" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/folder3/" [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev.website.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .php$
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]

# Rewriting url
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ rewrite.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ rewrite.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /rewrite.php?c=$1&p=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ /rewrite.php?c=$1&p=$2 [L]
```

And my seconde .htaccess (dev.website.com) :

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error404.html

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /dev

# Stuff to let through (ignore)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/folder1/" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/folder2/" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/folder3/" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .php$
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]

# Rewriting url
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ rewrite.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ rewrite.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /rewrite.php?c=$1&p=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ /rewrite.php?c=$1&p=$2 [L]
```

I have done research and a colleague also researched but there is absolutely nothing that can help us.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

For the first file just add an Alias and point it to your htdocs or public_html or the website.com path directory. You can remove all other stuff if not using it.

Ie:

```
Alias /dev "/var/www/public_html"
```

And for the second file you don't have to do anything as it works as expected.

Comment: I doesn't have access to the config file of my provider. I'm limited to use the .htaccess file to do that.

Comment: In the first or in the seconde .htaccess ?

Comment: It doesn't work. I'm trying different ways with you answer now.